# list is not sorting at all

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am updating a list and then trying to sort the list putting the highest `sVar1` at the front of the list, but it is not doing it, i'm using 6.0 VS

```
while(Iter != m_SomeList.end())
{
    if((*Iter)->sVar1 == 1) 
    {
        (*Iter)->sVar1++;
    }

    Iter++;
}

m_SomeList.sort(Descending());

Iter = m_SomeList.begin();

while(Iter != m_SomeList.end())
    {
        //now display the content of the list
```

my descending sort function

```
struct Descending : public greater<_LIST_DETAIL*> 
{
    bool operator()(const _LIST_DETAIL* left, const _LIST_DETAIL* right)
    {
        return (left->sVar1 > right->sVar1);
    }
};
```

can anyone spot whats wrong?

edit: updated code, it contained typos...

Comment: Should it not be `left->sVar1 > right->sVar1` ?

Comment: For the love of whatever God you believe in, **GET OFF OF VS 6.0**!!

Comment: Note there is a trailing `;` on the `while`, meaing the code in the following `{}` will be executed exactly once.

Comment: @hmjd Wouldn't that be an infinite loop?

Comment: This is an infinite or null loop: `while(Iter != m_SomeList.end());`

Comment: Also, names starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved in any scope.

Comment: Why do you inherit from `greater<_LIST_DETAIL*>`?

Answer (score 2):

This is just all kinds of messed up.

First, you do not derive from `std::greater` -- you either *use* `std::greater` directly, as in:

(psudocode, uncompiled)

```
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater() );
```

...or, if that's no good for you, write your own functor by deriving from `std::unary_function`:

```
struct Descending : public unary_function<bool, _LIST_DETAIL>
{
    bool operator()(const _LIST_DETAIL* left, const _LIST_DETAIL* right) const // note const
    {
        return (left->sVar1 > right->sVar1);
    }
};
```

Second, the use of leading underscores followed by an upper case name is reserved by the language.

Third, you are using a 14-year old compiler that MicroSoft has terminated all support for years ago.  What's more, by today's standards it is a stinking pile of junk.  It wasn't even very good when it was new.  You need to get off of VS 6.0.